# How to update the model dynamically in MVC5 (Ajax / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple ASP.net MVC5 website with Code-first EF. I would like to learn how to automatically update/refresh the view-models so that the user sees updated information.

The website is a simple auction site and I would like the current bid amount to automatically refresh in a user's view. The refreshing could be either server-pushed or client-polled; I don't mind which.

My current understanding is that this can be achieved using an Ajax toolkit or using jQuery. But I have not used these technologies before and docs/tutorials for this scenario seem to be lacking. I would very much appreciate a couple of pointers as to where I can start reading relevant material about the options and how to go about this seemingly simple task.

A short code sample would also be of great benefit.

Comment: Look into [Getting started with SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5)

Comment: @Murali Yes but that tutorial doesn't show updating the MVC view-model specifically.

Answer (score 0):

For a client-polled solution, you can use MVC "Partial views" and jQuery.

A quick guide to get started is here: http://www.yodotnet.com/post/2012/02/12/MVC-Makes-AJAX-easier.aspx.

More about partial views here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels.